# iOS Simulator HTML Web Page: Scrolling a text box with mouse

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Using the iOS Simulator and viewing a html page with a text box that has scrolling content, how do you use the mouse to scroll that text region?

On a real iOS device you simply press and hold and drag on the text box, but on the simulator doing that with a mouse scrolls the entire screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a simulator and not an emulator. You can use the simulator to 'test' how it looks like but you cannot test all of the features. The simulator is just an iframe sized to the resolution of an iPhone or whatever.